# Algorithm to compute shape and volume of polyhedrons (polytope) formed by finite planes

Tags: graphs, computational-geometry

Definition: In geometry, a polyhedron (plural polyhedra or polyhedrons) is solid in three dimensions with flat polygonal faces, straight edges, and sharp corners or vertices.

We have a closed domain with a certain number of faces (a cube,  pyramids). For example: Imagine we distribute n finite plane (for simplicity flat circular disc objects with a given location, diameter, and orientation) within a closed domain. These plates within region intersect each other as well as with boundaries of the domain. As a result of these intersections, some closed polyhedrons (Convex or Concave) may be formed.

The Objective is to find the shape and volume of polyhedrons formed by the intersection of these distributed finite plates.

I am not Computer Engineer nor mathematics. I have done a quick research and I found some keywords and topics (Spatial occupancy enumeration, Cell decomposition, Boundary representation among others.). I guess this problem should be well known and well studied in some fields. If you know an algorithm for that or any open source software that can be used for solving the above problem please let me know. I really appreciate any clues.
[image: a closed polyhedron formed intersections of finite plates]

Comment: There is a bit of explanation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Volume).

Comment: Thank you. As you mentioned there is a bit but not any complete explanation or algorithm.  The prerequisite step in my problem is how to detect that a polyhedron is formed  (closed polyhedron). I believe this related to graph theory?!